# Xcode Archives being recognized as macOS apps instead of iOS after importing to new machine

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I recently moved my user Library/developer/xcode folder to my new machine to try to keep the same settings. Upon opening the organizer on my new machine I noticed the applications are all under macOS where they should be on the iOS applications side. They also do not have the correct application icons. The older machine still has the proper organization and icons. Any ideas what I could be missing? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I realized when I copied the archives from my machine the contents of each of the archives were missing some files. The best way to copy everything was by compressing the archives folder and transfer it to the new machine and it worked!